# Apache Camel: How to finish a route after an "inOnly" child-route has finished?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to create a route that performs the following steps

1. Read File
2. Split file into lines
3. Unmarshall line using BeanIO
4. Call (expensive and time-consuming) Processor

I want to finish this route after all lines have been processed.

So the basic layout of my route looks like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .pollEnrich("file:..")
    .split(bodyAs(String.class).tokenize(RECORD_DELIMITER))
    .unmarshal(beanIODataFormat)
    .process(doTheWork);
```

Now I want to parallelize the `doTheWork` processor in order to speed up processing, as this operation is thread-safe and the execution order does not matter.

The easiest approach would be to parallelize the splitter by adding `.parallelProcessing()`, however, this is not possible, as the BeanIO Processing is not thread-safe (see [DateTypeHandlerSupport not thread-safe](https://code.google.com/archive/p/beanio/issues/131)). Therefore I want the unmarshalling to be done synchronously and start parallel processing thereafter.

However, as I'm in an InOut/Request-Reply exchange mode, I cannot just use the SEDA component with multiple processors, as the splitter will wait for the current sub-message to be completely processed, before it sends the next line as sub-message.

Instead I have to send the message as an asynchronous inOnly request, in order to "encourage" the splitter to send the next line:

```
from("direct:start")
    .pollEnrich("file:..")
    .split(bodyAs(String.class).tokenize(""))
    .unmarshal((DataFormatDefinition)null)
    .inOnly("seda:child");

from("seda:child?concurrentConsumers=5")
    .process(doTheWork);
```

However, if I do this the first route finishes as soon as it has delivered all messages to the child route.

Is there any way to make sure that the first route only finishes after all messages in child route have been processed?
Or how can I achieve to process "the real work" in parallel but the perform the unmarshalling sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you could use an `AggregationStrategy` on your first split to create a `List<YourBeanIOFormat>` and then have a second split where you can process each individual object in parallel.

```
.split(body())
.parallelProcessing()
.process(doTheWork)
```

Now, I'm not that familiar with the Java DSL so this might not be 100 % correct syntactically, but hopefully you get the idea.